# Problem installing plyr package

Tags: pip, cmus

I'm trying to install lyvi (command line lyrics viewer) from [here](https://github.com/ok100/lyvi).
So during installing plyr which one of the dependencies I got that issue:

```
    Collecting plyr
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/85/3b9928e2bfa38d4645c231dfc99c483af0a9e0da353af2cfd464645244f8/plyr-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-atdqke/plyr/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
    ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
    /tmp/pip-build-atdqke/plyr/
```

I've searched Google first, but no help. What should I do?

Comment: »»No module named Cython.Distutils«« : `sudo apt install cython`

Comment: Look what I got: [here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZRkFu7ZEY0SC7nNDVHjGYNjWaDAky9yNzL7) @KnudLarsen

Comment: Images with text are not at all appreciated. Please use copy-paste to create a TextFile.txt .

Comment: I managed to read the black image, by using some "magnifying equipment".   Missing `glyr/glyr.h` . Install `libglyr-dev`